# is there a way to use the PyScripter python interpreter in debug mode?

Tags: python, debugging, pyscripter

I have a script I want to debug that has classes and functions that I want to test interactively in the interpreter window of PyScripter.  I'd like to be able to do this in debug mode.  Is this possible?

Comment: Question is only for application help as subsequent comments demonstrate.  Shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, pyscripter does not have this capability.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). You can call your program's main function from within the interpreter, if you want to.

```
import pdb
def main():
    a, b = 3, 4 # Set some variables.
    d = {1:'a'}
    pdb.set_trace()
    print "All done."
```

Then, in the interpreter:

```
>>> from testme import main
>>> main()
>>> p a
3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide an example?  How would pdb recognize the breakpoints assigned in pyScripter?

Comment: I don't know about pyScripter, but you can insert breakpoints with pdb by calling `pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: The question is pretty clearly and specifically about pyScripter.  Does this answer have any application to pyScripter?  For example, does pyScripter use pdb under the covers?

Comment: If you're looking for application help, you should either try the forums for that application or at least use superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that pyScripter only allows debugging of single thread applications, and breakpoints only work in an applications main thread. You may need to look at an external debugger like [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/).

Comment: I'm not starting new threads.  I just want to run the debugger on the interpreter thread.

Answer (score 0):

PyScripter Actually has a built in debugger

Place a breakpoint on the side of the code (little dot on the edge|or| click in the code and push "F5") and then push "F9" to run in debug mode... and the "F8" to step over.

Note: This is PyScripter Specific